# How to make universal class method?

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

Is there any way to make a class template function?

So for example

```
//Warning: this is conceptual pseudo-code

template<typename TemplateClass, TemplateItem>
TemplateClass &TemplateClass::operator=(TemplateItem &B)
{
   Item = B.Item;
   return *this;
}

//or...

template<typename TemplateClass, TemplateItem>
TemplateClass &TemplateClass::Assignment(TemplateItem &B)
{
   Item = B.Item;
   return *this;
}

Assignment<TestA,TestB>(B);
```

Or something along those lines.

It isn't just for assignments, I'll comment.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I have no clue what you're asking. What is the function supposed to do?

Comment: It's basically a method template that can work for any class and take any template item. IE I can template similar assignment operations into one call rather than duplicating numerous lines of code for subclasses with different class returns.

Comment: in that case, just make it a non-member function?

Comment: What is the 2nd parameter `TemplateItem` ? What is `Item` inside it ? Is these methods are member of some `class` ?

Comment: @jalf: Because it needs to be able to return the class itself (hence *this).

Comment: @iammilind: Item is assumed to be a class, but it may just be: (*this) = ItemCopy; It's pseudo-code. Don't worry about semantics too much.

Comment: @SSight3: So? A non-member function would take the class as one of its parameters. Then it can simply return that parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I think a non-member operator function is what you're looking for.

Comment: What is the final line supposed to *do*?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Call the previous (template method?) function. It's just concept code, not valid in any way.

Comment: @jalf: Self defeating (and recursive) if I have to pass both the classes to an assignment function that... calls an assignment... function (Assignment calling operator=). Also, consider private/protected variables.

Comment: @SSight3: I understand that, but the previous function is a member function, so who's getting what assigned? If you're already calling this inside a class member function, then why not just say `Item = B.Item;` directly? What's the point of this indirection?

Comment: @KerrekSB: TestA is being assigned information from TestB (which we assume are internally similar) that they both have in common. Then the same function could be re-used for <TestA,TestC> and so on and so forth. Given TestA could never be given anything more than what already exists in TestA.

Comment: @SSight3: I understand that too, but I'm still at a loss how your construction is any improvement. You still need to know everything about the type of `B`. I just don't see what this generalizes in a useful way. That's just be my problem, of course, but at the moment I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: @SSight3: I still don't see the problem. Look at how things like `operator+` or `operator<<` are *already* defined as non-member functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure I'll get bashed by the "preprocessor is evil" group, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
#define DEFINE_ASSIGNMENT(mainClass,memberClass,member)        \
mainClass & mainClass::operator = (const memberClass & rhs)    \
{                                                              \
    member=rhs.member;                                         \
    return *this;                                              \
}

DEFINIE_ASSIGNMENT(TestA,TestB,Item)
```

Comment: Thats an excellent idea. I quite like it, and yes it is the sort of thing I'm after. Upvote for ingenuity. I was hoping for a template method so inheritance could occur, but failing that (if no-one can offer a viable method), I'll select this.  I'm getting too much duplicate code (but I can't use default or inheritance due to return issues).

Comment: Could you tell me what the '\' does? Thank you.

Comment: @SSight3 Ending a line with ``\`` is the line continuation character. Normally `#define` directives stop at the end of the line, the ``\`` tell the preprocessor to keep going. They can also be used to extend single line `//` comments, but several compilers will warn about using them like that. The ``\`` must be at the end of the line, it can't have any whitespace afterwards.

Comment: You've taught me two new things. I'll accept simply because it's nice to get an answer like this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add something into a class's definition. You can't force a class to have a particular member function. Once you put the `;` on a class definition, it has been defined, and it cannot be altered. So if you want to have a member of a class, it has to be declared *within* the class definition.

Now, the general way to extend functionality like this is to use a non-member function:

```
template<typename ClassName, typename Other>
ClassName &SomeFunc(ClassName &myType, const Other &theOther);
```

This function would return `myType`.

Obviously, that's not going to help with operators that have to be members of a class, like assignment. But there's nothing you can do about that. The most you can do is have the assignment operator call the non-member function, so all of the actual work goes on in there.

But that's the best you can do.